# How to change the language in busybox

Tags: linux, initramfs, busybox, language

I turned off the computer, but when I opened it again, it gave me an error:

[image: error]

I find the solution of it,(i need to write `fsck /dev/sda8`) however my keyboard is in russian, so i can not type anything in english.

I started search about the problem and found it https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1002358.html. This guy had a similar problem, so i tried it

```
press e for edit

highlight the kernel line and press e for edit

added set LANG=en_us

press enter, then b to boot.
```

but it also did not change the language in busybox

How can i change the language in busybox?

Comment: If you do not get a satisfactory answer, you could boot to a live USB and run fsck from there.

Comment: how can i do it? @KGIII

Comment: Most any live distro should do the trick, but you can see directions [here](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/linux/fsck-command-in-linux#2-Running-fsck-using-a-live-USB).

Comment: Will try it in the morning and will update the situation, thanks @KGIII

Answer (score 1):

Does this article help any?: https://ilikelinux69.github.io/How-to-change-the-keyboard-layout-in-Busybox.

Comment: How can i type it, if i can not type in english =(

Comment: Oh, forgot about that. Unless you can figure out how to use UTF-8 encoding to type English characters (links: https://www.maketecheasier.com/quickly-type-special-characters-linux/ and https://www.utf8-chartable.de/) then you probably need to buy an English QWERTY keyboard.